# How to change letters in a string entered by the user?

Tags: python

I have a python question called the "Password modifier" where a user enters a password of their choice (i.e `mypassword`) and the program needs to change the following.

```
i becomes !
a becomes @
m becomes M
B becomes 8
o becomes .
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share your attempt with us

Comment: You might be interested in [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.translate` and `str.maketrans`

```
>>> s = 'mypassword'
>>> s.translate(s.maketrans('iamBo', '!@M8.'))
'Myp@ssw.rd'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also harcode the shifting letters. Answers below are better but you can go like:

```
new_pass = ''
for char in password:
    if char == 'i':
        new_pass += '!'
    elif char == 'a':
        new_pass +='@'
    elif char == 'm':
        new_pass +='M'
    .
    .
    .
    else:
        new_pass += char
```

Comment: If the others' answer are better why add another answer ?

Comment: It seems to me a homework to introductory python lessons homework, project etc. Since other answers involve modules and other datatypes like dicts, mine was the simplest answer. Owner of the question may not know the dicts or working with modules yet.

Comment: Ok you are right so I will flag the question as off topic : Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with this lab. The easiest approach is to use the replace() feature. Don't forget to use string concatenation for the "q*s" needed at the end of the modified password:

```
user_input = input()
string_append = "q*s"

user_input = (user_input.replace('i', '!').replace('a','@')
              .replace('m', 'M').replace('B', '8').replace('o','.'))

print(user_input + string_append)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct input for this lab 4.15.1: LAB: Password modifier

```
word = input()
password = ''
word = word.replace('i','!')
word = word.replace('a','@')
word = word.replace('m','M')
word = word.replace('B','8')
word = word.replace('o','.')
word = word + 'q*s'
print(word)
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using the replace method for each character?

```
>>> password = 'mypassword'
>>> password = password.replace('a','@')
>>> print(password)
myp@ssword
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
chars={'i': '!', 'a': '@', 'm': 'M', 'B': '8', 'o':'.'}
password = input("Your password: ")
for x in password:
    if x in chars:
        password=password.replace(x, chars[x])

print(password)
```

Answer (score -2):

1.Setup initial replacement....

```
text = "iamBo"
repl = "!@M8."
trans = str.maketrans(text,repl)
```

2.Get the password....

```
password = input()
```

3.Print the password....

```
print(password.translate(trans))
```

Comment: I really don't understand why you post an answer which is a paste from @Jab 's answer 22 minutes later. Before answering please look a the others' answer. If your answer has no added value restrain from posting it.